# How to include specific modules in flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a private npm package with flow type annotations under `node_modules`.
I want to include only that package so I don't need to create libdef for it manually.

**directory structure**

```
node_modules/
  @my-company/private-module1
  public-module1
  public-module2
  .
  .
  .
```

I tried the following `.flowconfig` but it didn't work.

**doesn't work**

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
!./node_modules/@my-company/
[include]
[libs]
[options]
```

**doesn't work either**

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
[include]
./node_modules/@my-company/
[libs]
[options]
```

How can I achieve this?
I think I'm missing something basic...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a great solution because it looks like ocaml regexps don't allow for negative lookaheads.

For that reason, I've generally seen that when a project needs to ignore any `node_modules`, then `[ignore]` is configured as a black list with a lot of listings.

Since it looks like you're looking to ignore all node_modules anyway except your company's scoped packages, you might be better just ignoring all public node_modules and any scoped node_modules that you don't want flow to crawl.

```
[ignore]
; Ignore any public packages
.*/node_modules/[a-zA-Z-]+/.*

; Ignore specific scoped packages
.*/node_modules/@ignorescope/.*

[include]

[libs]

[options]
```

Comment: It works! I wish there were a better way to do this but it's good enough for us. Thanks!